# Is it possible to draw a nonprinting box around text, as in the hyperref package?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, boxes

I would like to be able to draw a box that shows up on in the PDF but does not print, just like the boxes around links that are made using the `hyperref` package.

I would like to put a `minipage` environment with multiple paragraphs inside the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `pdfcomment` package that Martin mentioned.

Upsides:

- doesn't link anywhere
- doesn't change the cursor to the hand pointer when pointing at the text.

Downsides:

- will most likely only work with Adobe Reader (doesn't work with GhostView and Sumatra)
- you have to find the coordinates for the rectangle manually ("To avoid the method ’trail [sic] and error’ you can load the PDF file with the
  Ghostscript viewer, which is capable of showing the cursor position in it’s
  status line.", [pdfcomment documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfcomment/doc/pdfcomment.pdf))
- will or will not print the box depending on the user's setting in the print window; "print document" (doesn't print box) or "print document and markup" (prints box).
- changes the cursor when pointing at the box/border; box is clickable and becomes "selected" when clicked

As for the coordinates:

> You can use the option line for defining the coordinates of lines in
>   certain PDF annotations, e. g. in the form `{x1 y1 x2 y2}`. The origin
>   is in the bottom left page corner. The given numbers will be
>   interpreted as Postscript points (LaTeX unit: bp (big points)), as
>   usual in PDF documents.

([pdfcomment documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfcomment/doc/pdfcomment.pdf))

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\pdflinecomment[type=polyline,lineend={/None},% = line with >2 "corners", no arrowhead
line={120 720 120 570 480 570 480 720 120 720},% adapt to your document
color=green,linewidth=1.5pt% adapt to your liking
]{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The border is a PDF annotation and as I saw in the `hyperref` code part of the hyperlink. Adding it without a link is seems to be not possible using existing LaTeX packages. The related `pdfcomments` package also provides some annotations but also no border only AFAIK. It might be possible using some direct PDF code using `\pdfliteral`, but you would need to know the PDF commands for this.

However you can add the border by placing it in a `\hyperref` or `\href`, but both do not allow paragraphs as content and generate a very tight border. You could use the v0.5 or higher of the `adjustbox` package (relative new) to box the `minipage` first which avoids the paragraph issue, add a margin if wanted and feed it to a `\hyperref` which e.g. simply points to the current page. The border color can be configured as described in the `hyperref` manual.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newenvironment{hborderbox}[1]{%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=#1,margin=1ex,precode=\hyperlink{page:\the\numexpr\arabic{page}-1\relax}}%
}{%
    \end{adjustbox}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{hborderbox}{.5\textwidth}
    \lipsum[1]\par\lipsum[2]
\end{hborderbox}


\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

it needs `\endgraf` instead of `\par`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand\TBox[1]{\href{http://tug.org}{%
  \tabular{c}\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}\rule{0pt}{3ex}%
  #1\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{0ex}\end{minipage}\endtabular}}

\begin{document}

\TBox{\blindtext \endgraf\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: simple and elegant.

Comment: This doesn't work with normal paragraphs. `Paragraph ended before \href@split was complete`